# How to search itunes store for app with applescript?

Tags: macos, app-store, applescript

How to search itunes store for app with applescript? I have been stuck on this and recording doesn't work in itunes.

Answer (score 3):

I haven’t seen recording work in years. In this case, though, I’m not sure it could. While iTunes is scriptable, it doesn’t appear to have any direct means to perform a search of the Stores.

However, there is a means to perform a search using a URL and “open location”. It would look something like:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    open location "itms://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?WOURLEncoding=ISO8859_1&lang=1&output=lm&country=US&media=software&term=ia%20Writer"
end tell
```

Put the text you want to search for after &term=; here, that’s ia%20Writer (with the %20 meaning a space).

This combines info from [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2008/12/linking-to-the-stars-hacking-itunes-to-solicit-reviews/) and [Doug’s AppleScripts](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/2014/03/itunes-store-power-search-at-your-fingertips/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can use an **AppleScript** `display dialog` to enter what **App** to search for in the **iTunes Store** using the answer provided by Jerry Stratton:

- If the *search* has *spaces* in it, the script replaces it with `%20` for you.

---

```
set theAppSearch to ""
set theAppSearch to text returned of (display dialog "App Search iTunes Store for:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2)
if theAppSearch is not "" then
    set theAppSearch to my replaceSpaces(theAppSearch)
    tell application "iTunes"
        activate
        open location "itms://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?WOURLEncoding=ISO8859_1&lang=1&output=lm&country=US&media=software&term=" & theAppSearch
    end tell
end if
on replaceSpaces(theString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {" "}
    set theString to text items of theString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"%20"}
    set theString to theString as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
    return theString
end replaceSpaces
```